# Django | blog.Post.author: (fields.E301) Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'

Tags: django, django-models

Tras crear aplicacion Users y crear modelo importando AbstractBaseUser. Al hacer makemigrations me devuelve un error. No se si puede ser que el modelo Post tiene una columna llamada author que utiliza 'auth.User' y de alguna manera se haya cambiado su ruta con Users.

ERROR:

```
ERRORS:
blog.Post.author: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

**Archivo** models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
        email = models.FileField()
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        last_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    
        def get_short_name(self):
            return self.username
    
        def get_full_name(self):
            return self.nombre + '' + self.apellido1 + '' + self.apellido2
```

**Archivo** settings.base.py

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
'users',

#...

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

**Archivo** blog.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre es más recomendable personalizar el modelo de usuario antes de realizar alguna migración. Ver: [Cambiando el modelo de usuario en un proyecto existente](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project)

Una posible solución podría ser ajustar tu modelo `Post` para que el autor apunte a tu nuevo modelo `User`

```
 from django.conf import settings 

 class Post(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        ...
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto Orlando Hernandez. Muchas gracias.